# Equation of circle after rolling

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Q: A circle of radius $5$ units touches both the axes and lies in the first quadrant. If the circle makes one complete roll on $+ x$-axis, then what will be its equation in the new position $?$

I got my answer as $x^2 +y^2 -x(10+20\pi)-10y+100\pi^2+100\pi+25=0.$
Is it correct?

Comment: $(x-5-10\pi)^2+(y-5)^2 = 5^2$ if it rolls clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

The circle of radius $5$ has equation $(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2=5^2$.

One complete revolution covers a distance of $2\pi r$, or $10\pi$ in this case.

So the centre also shifts by $10\pi$ to the right.
So the new equation is

$$(x-5-10\pi)^2+(y-5)^2=5^2$$

So:
$$x^2-2(5+10\pi)x+(5+10\pi)^2+y^2-10y+25=25$$
$$x^2-(10+20\pi)x+25+100\pi+100\pi^2+y^2-10y=0$$
Thus:
$$x^2+y^2-x(10+20\pi)-10y+100\pi^2+100\pi+25=0$$
So your proof is correct.

Comment: Welcome on MSE! I edited the answer as requested. You will probably want to have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check the link and hopefully type better from now on.

Answer (score 2):

The circle travels a distance of $2\pi\cdot 5=10\pi$ units to the right after one full rotation. It's original equation is $(x-5)^2+(y-5)^2=5^2$. Hence, its new position is
$$(x-5-10\pi)^2+(y-5)^2=5^2\iff (x-5(1+2\pi))^2+(y-5)^2=25\\\iff x^2-10(1+2\pi)x+25(1+2\pi)^2+y^2-10y+25=25\\\iff x^2+y^2-x(10+20\pi)-10y+100\pi^2+100\pi+25=0$$
So yes, you're correct.